# Desconectar usuário ao entrar em outra conta

Tags: php, session

Olá queria saber como faz para desconectar um usuário se ele entra em outra conta no mesmo navegador com o mesmo IP, uso session do PHP, se puderem me ajudar agradeço muito!! Pois o usuário pode logar em quantas contas ele quiser.

Comment: Se você simplesmente armazenar o ID do usuário conectado na session, não tem como acontecer isso que está dizendo, pois ao reconectar, o ID anterior é sobreescrito. O problema é na arquitetura atual do seu código. Grande chance de qualquer tentativa de contornar a situação ser pior do que consertar o problema no lugar certo. Agora, se você quiser que o usuário não conecte em navegadores diferentes, ou em aba privada, o problema é outro (e qualquer tentativa de resolver pode afetar usuários que compartilham o mesmo IP). O ideal continua sendo resolver na arquitetura em vez de fazer remendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o melhor a se fazer seria armazenar e consultar o banco de dados para verificar se não houve conexão em outra conta.

Por exemplo:

Quando se conectar é criado isto:

```
$_SESSION['conectado'] = true;
$_SESSION['id'] = '1';
$_SESSION['confirmado'] = time();
```

Quando acessa outra página (e faz uma requisição por ajax, enfim!):

```
if($_SESSION['confirmado'] < (time() - 300)){

  $query = mysqli_query('SELECT EValido FROM usuario WHERE id = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"');
  $valido = mysqli_fetch_all($query);

  if($valido[0] === '1'){

     mysqli_query('UPDATE usuario SET EValido = 0 WHERE id != "'.$_SESSION['id'].'" AND ip = "'.$ip.'"');
     $_SESSION['confirmado'] = time();

  }else{

     // Não está conectado! 
     session_destroy();

  }


}
```

> Isso é só um exemplo!

Isso irá fazer com que em algumas situações o servidor verifique se está valido ou não, fazendo o `session_destroy` caso retorne que está válido. Tal verificação seria feita depois de 5 minutos após última.

Para que atualize o valor de `EValido` do banco de dados você deve verificar o IP (nesse caso) e comparar com outros já conectados, assim se outro usuário com o mesmo IP conectar o antigo irá ser desconectado.

> **ATENÇÃO:**
>
> Redes publicas, abertas e compartilhadas fazem com que um mesmo IP seja usado para vários dispositivos e usuários. Portanto, desconectar os usuários apenas porque possuem um mesmo IP pode ser um grande erro e incomodo para vários utilizadores, veja se isso é realmente necessário! Além disso existem pessoas que podem possuir dois provedores de internet, muita das vezes usando [load balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Load_Balancing), portanto os dois IPs podem ficar sendo alternados a cada requisição, o que pode causar desconexão constante!
>
> Para piorar a situação existe a escassez do IPv4. Tal escassez faz com que várias pessoas, de uma mesma provedora, possam possuir um mesmo IP! Isso ocorre pelo uso do CGNAT.  Existe [inclusive existe um vídeo de sobre isso criado pelo NIC.br](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uxu0ivaDAnc) e [também existe uma postagem](http://ipv6.br/post/tutorial-log-da-porta-de-origem-para-ipv4-compartilhado/), com uma suposta solução! *Sinceramente, não sei muitas informações sobre o IPv6, porém em Dezembro de 2015 o uso de [IPv6 era de ~6,42%](http://imasters.com.br/noticia/adocao-de-ipv6-aumenta-significativamente-no-brasil/), não espero que o uso de IPv6 tenha se expandido tão rápido. Isso apenas considerando o Brasil.*